# CSS: How to replace span with an attribute?

Tags: css

```css
span[email].g2 {}

span[email].g2::after {
  content: attr(email);
}
```

```html
<div class="iw ajw">
  <span translate="no" class="hb">to <span email="myemail@example.com" name="Mark" data-hovercard-id="myemail@example.com" class="g2" data-hovercard-owner-id="119">Mark</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I want to replace "Mark" with "myemail@example.com".

I got the email to show up with `content: attr(email)` but I can't figure out how to hide my name without also hiding the after content.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

```css
span[email].g2 {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* alpha 0 ~ it's hidden */
    position: relative;
}

span[email].g2::after {
    content: attr(email);
    color: black; /* by default, it inherits alpha 0, so you force black */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="iw ajw">
  <span translate="no" class="hb">to <span email="myemail@example.com" name="Mark" data-hovercard-id="myemail@example.com" class="g2" data-hovercard-owner-id="119">Mark</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

EDIT:

### Solution 2

I found another simpler solution with `font-size` with text before and text after.

```css
span[email].g2 {
    font-size: 0;
}

span[email].g2::after {
    content: attr(email);
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="iw ajw">
  text before
  <span translate="no" class="hb">to <span email="myemail@example.com" name="Mark" data-hovercard-id="myemail@example.com" class="g2" data-hovercard-owner-id="119">Mark</span>
  </span>
  text after
</div>
```

Comment: There's stuff to the right of the span too. I think that absolute positioning is causing the content to get all jumbled up.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the data attribute for custom attributes.
 `<span translate="no" class="hb">to <span data-email="myemail@example.com" data-name="Mark" data-hovercard-id="myemail@example.com" class="g2" data-hovercard-owner-id="119">Mark</span> </span>`

This can be accessed and set in javascript by:`document.querySelector("span").dataset.name;`

Or accessed in css by:

`span[data-name="Mark"]{ }`

Comment: Yeah.. not my HTML. Trying to override styles on a certain website.

Comment: Oh, that's weird HTML then. Anyways, are you set on doing it in css? Why not just change innerText in Javascript?

Comment: If I have to, then maybe. I'd need a Chrome extension to inject the JS and poll the page for elements every few seconds.

Comment: add a script in a chrome extension along with css doesn't take much more work. In the manifest, right below where you add the css file, you add the scripts